# Jquery ignores my if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a little script that hides the navigation when you scroll down and shows the navigation when scroll up.

But for some reason my script ignores the statement.

```
// the check function

function checkWidth(code) {
            $(window).on('resize' , function () {
                if( $(window).width() > 1000) {
                    code

                }
            })
        }

// function I want to use when width is bigger then 1000px

checkWidth(
        $(window).bind('mousewheel', function(i) {
            if(i.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 > 0) {
                $('.footer').slideDown();
            } else {
                $('.footer').slideUp();
            }
        })
);
```

Comment: If you are talking about the first if inside the resize event: you only get the width once, you never update `winWid` to the new width

Comment: Your script does not "ignore" any statement, and neither does the language (which is JavaScript). You made a mistake. Did you consider debugging your script to find out where you made that mistake?

Comment: Which part of your code tells the computer to update the `winWid` variable on resize?

Comment: with this alone you can check if the user is scrolling up or down:

`$(window).on('mousewheel', function(i) { if (i.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 > 0) { console.log('scrolling up'); } else { console.log('scrolling down'); } });`

With this you can hide or show your navigation, don't understand for what you're checking the width.

Comment: Now we have no way to verify and investigate your claim, because the only pertinent code is literally `code`. Provide your [MCVE] please.

Comment: If you are wanting the `$(window).bind()` call to be passed and executed you need to wrap it in a function so it can be called from inside your if statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this code you can run a function if the user is scrolling up or down while the window width is above 1000px. I hope I understood you right.

```
var winWidth = $(window).width();
$(window).on('resize' , function () {
    winWidth = $(window).width();
});

$(window).on('mousewheel', function(i) {
    if (winWidth > 1000) {
        if (i.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 > 0) {
            console.log('scrolling up');
        } else {
            console.log('scrolling down');
        }
    }
});
```